# How to change the cell on the left of two rows to their right? (HTML/Tables...)

Tags: html, html-table

I like this code below to create a table; however, I would like to have the "x =" part to the right of the the fractional equation. At the moment, "x =" is to the left of the fractional equation.

How can I change the code, so that the "x =" is on the right?

```
<style>
td.upper_line { border-top:solid 1px black; }
table.fraction { text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
margin-top:0.5em; margin-bottom:0.5em; line-height: 2em; } 
</style>

<table class="fraction" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" nowrap="nowrap"> <i>x</i> = </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap"> <i>x</i> <sup>2</sup> + <i>x</i> + 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="upper_line">2 cos(<i>x</i>)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: didn't quite get your question. But I think [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) is a good solution for equations. [demo](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after? I have changed the x= to an =x so that the equation looks right.

```
<table class="fraction" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap">
        <i>x</i><sup>2</sup> + <i>x</i> + 1
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" nowrap="nowrap">
      =  <i>x</i>  
    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="upper_line">
        2 cos(<i>x</i>)
    </td>
</tr> </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
td.upper_line { border-top:solid 1px black; }
table.fraction { text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
margin-top:0.5em; margin-bottom:0.5em; line-height: 2em; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table class="fraction" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>

        <td nowrap="nowrap"> <i>x</i> <sup>2</sup> + <i>x</i> + 1</td>
                       <td  rowspan="2" nowrap="nowrap"> = <i>x</i>  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td class="upper_line">2 cos(<i>x</i>)</td>
    </tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean:

```
<td rowspan="2" nowrap="nowrap"> <i>x</i> = </td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"> <i>x</i> <sup>2</sup> + <i>x</i> + 1</td>
```

to

```
<td nowrap="nowrap"> <i>x</i> <sup>2</sup> + <i>x</i> + 1</td>
<td rowspan="2" nowrap="nowrap"> <i>x</i> = </td>
```